2d enemy patrolling in unity
I tried to set up a system where you set the right-left range for an enemy, without additional colliders or raycast so that it's simple and reusable, and I ran into this problem:
When I start the game and the enemy starts moving left, the first 'trip' taken is about 5 times longer than it should be, but when the enemy turns around, it works like it should.
The range is ok and it changes the direction faced. It's just the first time it starts moving that this happens.
Here's my code:
using UnityEngine;

public class playerscript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 1f; 
    public float maxX = 1f;
    public float minX = -1f; 

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private bool movingRight = false; 

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (movingRight)
        {
            if (transform.position.x >= maxX - speed * Time.deltaTime)
            {
                Flip();
            }
            else
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rb.velocity.y);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (transform.position.x <= minX + speed * Time.deltaTime)
            {
                Flip();
            }
            else
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, rb.velocity.y);
            }
        }
    }

    void Flip()
    { 
        movingRight = !movingRight;
        Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
        scale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = scale;
    }
}


Please explain what "the first 'trip' it takes it's like 5 times longer than it should" means. Is it taking a wrong route, the speed is slower, it collides or hits obstacles slowing it, it doesn't instantly start, there is an acceleration problem etc.? We can assume, but the rule I go by from experience is "never assume", it's easier if we know the real facts. Please give a few details. Also, tell us what you noticed in debugging sessions (and by that,, I mean code debugging, not using Debug.Log() necessarily, then again, any info might help).

Also, does this happen with only one character or every character? Does it happen on only one scene or every scene? Is it consistent on every execution? For example, does it happen in the current Editor session or even after restarting it? Can you reproduce it on every Play Scene or only after a domain reload? Can you reproduce it in a build executed inside the Unity Player? You did say "It's just for the first time it's starts moving that this happens" but "first time" can mean different things to different people. Every detail matters :)

You also didn't tell us how the unit starts its tasks. Is the GO enabled by default or after an event or trigger? Is there a hardcoded condition in code? Are there any disable mechanisms (such as component disabling, even if the GO is enabled) or any if-return statements? Are there any delays such as time stepping via deltaTime or CoRoutines used? What are maxX and speed? I assume floats. Do they have default values? What are they? Are they set in code in var declarations, Start(), Awake() or via serialization the Inspector? Do these values change? There are many possible causes.

BTW, I see you're using Time.deltaTime in FixedUpdate(). You need Time.fixedDeltaTime.

@TheNomad Time.deltaTime returns the fixedDeltaTime when called from FixedUpdate.

@Verpous True, but I find it error prone if you do decide to move code.

@TheNomad to answer your qs, when I start  the game the character goes to the left but way further than it's supposed to. Then it turns around and it's good. It's interacting wit hother objects as intended, this happes with every object i apply this script to, on every session, every execution, and on every scene.

The code looks fine so my guess is you are setting minX, maxX to values different than you expect. You understand that they're in global coordinates, right? Not relative to the object's starting position or anything. Try Debug.Logging the values of transform.position, minX, maxX, speed, etc. every frame and see where things go wrong.

I did a simple 2-square (player and ground) 2D game and I couldn't reproduce your issue. The first iteration has the same left-most distance as the second and the third and all the others. Are you sure the script in your game doesn't have other things that modify its variables or behavior?

Thanks to @Verpous I figured it out, basically i was thinking that minX, maxX are in relation to the object, but they refer to global values, so when minX was set to 1 and I spawn the character on x=20 on the map, he moves left till he reaches x=1 and the he proceeds to do his job. Thanks a lot guys.
